# Set another Class to Main Class Android

Tags: java, android, class, interface, splash-screen

i made a splash screen for my app (i know that it is not that important), so i made a new class .. it does not show error on android studio now .. the only problem i have is .. how can i change that (splash screen) class will show first before the main class ?? ..

i followed a quick tutorial about making a splashscreen on another website and this is what my [XML](http://pastebin.com/p9LzJU74) and [CLASS](http://pastebin.com/5VW6wTRk) structure looks like, PS i decided making a splash screen right after my app is already made, so i am editing my app .. thanks

Comment: You need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file. I suggest you do some research to understand its structure better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "splashScreen" activity to be the entrance of your application, add the declaration as the following to your manifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```